# What is the meaning of Output data rate of Bosch BMI270?

Tags: frequency, imu, data-rate, update

what is the meaning of ODR (output data rate)

[BMI270](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmi270-ds000.pdf) says it has 1.6kHz for accelerometer ODR

does it mean internal registers update rate is 1.6kHz

or

1.6kHz/(16bit x 3) = 33Hz ? (here 3 is, 3 axis)

or

1.6KHz/ (16bit) = 100Hz? (per each 16bit register)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > does it mean internal registers update rate is 1.6kHz

True. Think of it to be something like mesurement rate. It'll give you the updated data at a rate of 1.6kHz when you query through SPI or I²C.

Comment: so its the maximum sample rate the MCU can achieve? (ODR 1.6kHz = each accelerometer 16bit register update rate = maximum achievable sample rate for accelerometer data is 1.6kHz) correct me if this is wrong

Comment: @oppo yes. Even if you query faster it will probably give you the last updated content.